# gnome-settings-daemon not saving Settings after reboot; Mint 14 XFCE

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, reboot

I am running Linux Mint 14 with xfce on my Asus UX31A and switched to gnome-settings-daemon, because this way all the function keys work out of the box.

Disabled XFCE Volume Daemon as advised here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/95969/using-gnome-settings-daemon-in-xfce

Now my problem is that the settings get reset to default after rebooting. for example if I change scrolling to two finger scrolling it resets to edge scrolling after reboot, application autostart settings are reset, etc.